# turning a raw dataframe data into a dictionary with a list

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I am trying to turn this data (in a Dataframe):

```
         0         1
0   HT01  CC363292
29  RL01  CC363292
50  TN01  CC363292
4   BN02  CC363293
7   MR20  CC363294
9   TN01  CC363295
10  RL01  CC363296
13  HT01  CC363297
17  HT01  CC363298
21  SU01  CC363299
22  BN02  CC363300
25  MR20  CC363301
27  MR20  CC363302
54  BN02  CC363313
57  BN02  CC363314
60  BN02  CC363315
52  SU01  EA363303
32  RL01  EA363303
35  MR20  EA363304
37  HU01  EA363305
38  HU01  EA363306
39  BN02  EA363307
63  RL01  EA363311
66  MR20  EA363312
42  HT01  SC363308
46  RL01  SC363309
51  SP01  SC363309
53  FU01  SC363309
49  SP01  SC363310
```

into a dictionary that uses `col.0` as key and a list of matching `col.1` info (see below)

i.e.

```
temp_dict = {

CC363292 : [HT01, RL01, TN01]
CC363293 : [BN02]

}
```

I have tried using a for loop to append the list to the key with no luck.

can any one assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
zip_data = zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])

result = {}

for i in zip_data:
    result.setdefault(i[1], []).append(i[0])
```

This might work.

Answer (score 2):

The questions requires to group the rows by a column and list another column based on the groups. A quick solution can be:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
  [0, "HT01", "CC363292"],
  [29, "RL01", "CC363292"],
  [50, "TN01", "CC363292"],
  [4, "BN02", "CC363293"],
  [7, "MR20", "CC363294"],
  [9, "TN01", "CC363295"],
  [10, "RL01", "CC363296"],
  [13, "HT01", "CC363297"],
  [17, "HT01", "CC363298"],
  [21, "SU01", "CC363299"],
  [22, "BN02", "CC363300"],
  [25, "MR20", "CC363301"],
  [27, "MR20", "CC363302"],
  [54, "BN02", "CC363313"],
  [57, "BN02", "CC363314"],
  [60, "BN02", "CC363315"],
  [52, "SU01", "EA363303"],
  [32, "RL01", "EA363303"],
  [35, "MR20", "EA363304"],
  [37, "HU01", "EA363305"],
  [38, "HU01", "EA363306"],
  [39, "BN02", "EA363307"],
  [63, "RL01", "EA363311"],
  [66, "MR20", "EA363312"],
  [42, "HT01", "SC363308"],
  [46, "RL01", "SC363309"],
  [51, "SP01", "SC363309"],
  [53, "FU01", "SC363309"],
  [49, "SP01", "SC363310"],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Group by the third column.
# List the second column.
groups = df.groupby(df.columns[2])[df.columns[1]].apply(list)
print(groups)
```

The output should look similar to:

```
CC363292    [HT01, RL01, TN01]
CC363293                [BN02]
CC363294                [MR20]
CC363295                [TN01]
CC363296                [RL01]
CC363297                [HT01]
CC363298                [HT01]
CC363299                [SU01]
CC363300                [BN02]
CC363301                [MR20]
EA363311                [RL01]
EA363312                [MR20]
SC363308                [HT01]
SC363309    [RL01, SP01, FU01]
SC363310                [SP01]
```

To convert to a dictionary, use `dict(groups)` instead. The output should be:

```
{
  'CC363292': ['HT01', 'RL01', 'TN01'],
  'CC363293': ['BN02'],
  'CC363294': ['MR20'],
  'CC363295': ['TN01'],
  'CC363296': ['RL01'],
  'CC363297': ['HT01'],
  'CC363298': ['HT01'],
  'CC363299': ['SU01'],
  'CC363300': ['BN02'],
  'CC363301': ['MR20'],
  'CC363302': ['MR20'], 
  'CC363313': ['BN02'], 
  'CC363314': ['BN02'],
  'CC363315': ['BN02'],
  'EA363303': ['SU01', 'RL01'],
  'EA363304': ['MR20'],
  'EA363305': ['HU01'],
  'EA363306': ['HU01'],
  'EA363307': ['BN02'],
  'EA363311': ['RL01'],
  'EA363312': ['MR20'],
  'SC363308': ['HT01'],
  'SC363309': ['RL01', 'SP01', 'FU01'],
  'SC363310': ['SP01']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little familiar with Pandas and here is the solution I came up to:

```
# Create DataFrame from initial data
data = [
    ('HT01', 'CC363292'),
    ('RL01', 'CC363292'),
    ('TN01', 'CC363292'),
    ('BN02', 'CC363293'),
    ...
]

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['col1', 'col2'])

# This will create a such dataframe:
# col1 |     col2 |
# HT01 | CC363292 |
# RL01 | CC363292 |
# TN01 | CC363292 |
# BN02 | CC363293 |
# .... | ........ |

# The next step is to convert 'col2' to categorical
_df = pandas.get_dummies(data=df, columns=['col2'], prefix='', prefix_sep='')

# This will give us such result:
# col1 | CC363292 | CC363293 | ...
# HT01 |        1 |        0 | ...
# RL01 |        1 |        0 | ...
# TN01 |        1 |        0 | ...
# BN02 |        0 |        1 | ...
# .... | ........ | ........ | ...

# Then we'll create the simple lambda function to initialize our lists:
f = lambda col: [_df.col1[i] for i, val in enumerate(_df[col]) if val]

# And obtain the requested result using dict-comprehensions:
my_dict = {col: f(col) for col in _df.columns[1:]}

# Important: using _df.columns[1:] is not very universal, but
# will be ok for the problem you described
```